# How to generate an XML feed?

Tags: 7, feeds

I am creating an XML feed (`domain.com/content_type/feed`).

I looked into **RSS Publishing** and have turned it off, but do see where I can generate an XML feed: `Home » Administration » Configuration » Web services`

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module (Most popular)

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of
>   data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered
>   progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support
>   exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV
> - Microsoft XLS (or really simple HTML understood by Excel)
> - Microsoft DOC
> - Basic TXT
> - **XML**

Example:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also do it using the [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module

> Views Datasource is a set of plugins for Drupal Views for rendering
>   content in a number of shareable, reusable formats based on **XML**, JSON
>   and XHTML. These formats allow content in a Drupal site to be easily
>   used as data sources for Semantic Web clients and web mash-ups. Views
>   Datasource plugins output content from node lists created in the
>   Drupal Views interface in a variety of formats - XML data documents
>   using schemas like OPML and Atom, RDF data documents using a
>   vocabulary like FOAF, JSON data documents in a format like Exhibit
>   JSON, and XHTML data documents using a microformat like hCard.